# cypress request PATCH call for local stub server fails

Tags: automation, integration-testing, cypress, e2e-testing, stubbing

I have a local stub server which has a PATCH request. When I call this local endpoint inside cypress, it fails.
My cypress code

```
Cypress.Commands.add('callLocalAPI', (id: string = '1') => {
  const options = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: `${Cypress.env().baseUrl}test/api`,
    // failOnStatusCode: false,
    retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true,
    log: true,
    body: {
      id,
    },
  }

  // we need cy to visit the current URL so it grabs cookie
  // for our request
  cy.visit('/')
  cy.request(options).then((response) => {

    if (!String(response.body.id)) {
      console.error(response)
      throw Error(`Fail to get response with ${id}`)
    }
  })
})
```

then calling this custom cypress command

```
cy.callLocalAPI('2')
```

When I access this endpoint using postman (http://localhost:8882/test/api), I get the expected response with a status code of 200 so there is no issues with the mock server.

But when I run the cypress tests, I always get a 404.

```
Status: 404 - Not Found
Headers: {
  "server": "stubby/5.0.0 node/v12.19.0 (darwin x64)",
  "date": "Fri, 03 Sep 2021 03:36:49 GMT",
  "connection": "keep-alive",
  "keep-alive": "timeout=5",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
  const options = {
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: 'test/api',
    ...
```

From [Cypress docs - request](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Arguments)

> If you make a cy.request() after visiting a page, Cypress assumes the url used for the cy.visit() is the host.
> `cy.visit('http://localhost:8080/app')`
> `cy.request('users/1.json') //  url is  http://localhost:8080/users/1.json`

It may simply be that this line is missing a path separator

```js
url: `${Cypress.env().baseUrl}test/api`
```

---

**Cypress.env().baseUrl**

Note that the value for this string is

- taken from the file `cypress.env.json` (not `cypress.json`)

  ```js
  {
     "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8882/" 
  }
  ```
- or overridden in the command line
  `cypress open --env baseUrl=http://localhost:8882/`

Comment: no baseurl return - http://localhost:8080/ so no path separator is required for url

Comment: Why is no path separator required? If baseUrl is as you say, your request url you are using will be `localhost:8080test/api` - but it should be `localhost:8080/test/api`.

Comment: baseUrl returns http://localhost:8080 / (note the last backslash)

Comment: The comment is removing the backslash

Comment: And I note you are saying port 8080 here, but above with Postman you use port 8882. What gives?